# Display Custom CSS and HTML instructions for posts Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, admin, customization

I am creating a blog for some people that are going to be placing posts on their site within 5 different custom posts that i have created.

As some of the categories require the users to bullet point the post data (therefore creating ul>li ) so ensure it is styled correctly when it appears on the site.

To make sure that the editors of the site input data into the post admin area correctly i wish to either.

1. Display a image down the right hand side of the new / edit post screen which has instructions on how to create the custom post.

or / and

1. Have watermarked input forms (like where it sats "insert title here") to give a example on how the data should be displayed.

I am using the plugin more fields to display my input fields. this has the option to insert HTML and I have had mixed success with placing images and code in these as it seems sporadic if it works or not!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Si

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, a [custom meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) can solve this.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_54822_add_custom_box' );

function wpse_54822_add_custom_box() 
{
    $post_types = array( 'post', 'movies', 'testimonial' );

    foreach( $post_types as $box )
    {
        add_meta_box(
            'wpse_54822_sectionid',
            __( 'Instructions' ), 
            'wpse_54822_inner_custom_box',
            $box,
            'side'
        );
    }
}


function wpse_54822_inner_custom_box() 
{
    ?><pre>
&lt;b&gt;This text is bold&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;strong&gt;This text is strong&lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;i&gt;This text is italic&lt;/i&gt;
&lt;em&gt;This text is emphasized&lt;/em&gt;
&lt;code&gt;This is computer output&lt;/code&gt;</pre>
    <?php
}
```

Which results in:
[image: custom meta box with instructions]

---

Other possibility could be inserting a custom [Help Tab](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_help_tab).